# android calendar- changing the week text in calendarView

Tags: android

i created a simple calendarView:

```
<CalendarView
android:id="@+id/calendar"
android:layout_margin="10dp"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

it shows on top of the calander the first letter of every day in the week:
S M T W T F S

i want it will show the first three letters of every day:
SUN MON TUE WEN THU FRI SAT.

how to do it?